# Escape sequences \033[01;36m\] vs. \033[1;36m\] in PS1 in .bashrc: why the zero?

Tags: bash, debian, command-prompt, prompt, ansi-escape

I've just compared the $PS1 prompts in .bashrc on two of my Debian machines:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;36m\]\u\[\033[0;90m\]@\[\033[0;32m\]\h\[\033[0;90m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[0;90m\]\$\[\033[0m\] '

PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[1;36m\]\u\[\033[0;37m\]@\[\033[0;32m\]\h\[\033[0;37m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[0;37m\]\$\[\033[0m\] '
```

As you see, the first sequence says `\033[01;`, whereas the second has `\033[1;` on the same position.  Do both mean the same (I guess, bold) or do they mean something different?  Any idea why the zero has appeared or disappeared?  I have no recollection of having introduced/removed this zero myself. A Web search returns numerous occurrences both with and without zero.

Answer (score 0):

the ESC[#;#m escape is for the console font color. I've seen many subtle variations on escape implementations, so I'm not surprised. Regardless I think both should be interpreted the same way

Comment: Also variations within the Debian (and, perhaps, Ubuntu) world?

Comment: I've done incremental Yacto builds of the same project and ended up affecting how escapes got implemented in the resulting linux images for no reason I could ever point to

Answer (score 0):

"ANSI" numeric parameters are all decimal integers (see [ECMA-48](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-48_5th_edition_june_1991.pdf), section 5.4.1 *Parameter Representation*).  In section 5.4.2, it explains

> A parameter string consists of one or more parameter sub-strings, each of which represents a number
> in ***decimal*** notation.

A leading zero makes no difference.  Someone noticed the unnecessary character and trimmed it.

Comment: Thx! I'm a bit confused as for what the standard means by “bit combination in the range 03/12 to 03/15”. To me, a bit combination is a string of bits, i.e., a string of zeros and ones, e.g., *001101101*, but not *03/12* or *03/15*.

Comment: It's a roundabout way of using hexadecimal: `03/12` is like `0x3C` (it's a little easier to see if you read the standard, which has tables with  16 rows for the second part fo `03/12`).  For whatever reason, that's the jargon that the committee used ~1980...

Comment: Wow. Now it's more clear. However, this is a hell of a jargon because *0x3C* is not more or less a string of bits than *03/12*. :-)